# test is clear in ng-select if mouse click outside

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this `ng-select`

```
<ng-select
            style="width: 100%; margin-left: -5px"
            [(ngModel)]="List"
            [clearable]="false"
            autofocus
            formControlName="Email"
            (keyup)="BlurMethod($event)"
            #ngSelect
            (remove)="removeToItem($event)"
            [items]="to$ | async"
            bindLabel="e_mail1_Value"
            bindValue="e_mail1_Value"
            [addTag]="addTagPromise"
            [multiple]="true"
            [hideSelected]="true"
            [trackByFn]="trackByFn"
            [minTermLength]="2"
            [loading]="peopleLoading"
            typeToSearchText="Please enter"
            [typeahead]="toInput$"
            placeholder="Users"
            id="toMailId"
            [selectOnTab]="true"
          >
          </ng-select>
```

if i type some text and without clicking on tab click outside the screen then all the text in field is cleared i want to retain the value which i typed without clicking on tab also.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: you can use (change)="onChangeSelect($event)" or (onChange)="onChangeSelect($event)"

Comment: @ĐỗvănThắng I want to retain the typed text before select on tag when i click outside

Comment: @ĐỗvănThắng This is not working

Comment: this is what you need: https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focusmonitor